# C segmentation fault when reading separate strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a C program that reads in a **first name,** **last name**, and sometimes it **may** contain a **middle name** as well. In other words, I might be reading two strings or three depending on the input.

**Desired Output:**

last name, followed by a comma, followed the the initial of the first name, or in the case of a middle name, include both first name initial and middle name initials.

**Examples:**

**Input:**

```
John Smith

John David Smith

John D. Smith
```

**Output:**

```
Smith, J.

Smith, J. D.

Smith, J. D.
```

---

**My Attempt:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define size 20
#define max size*4
int main()
{
    char name[max];
    char first[size];
    char mid[size];
    char last[size];
    int read;

    /* Read the full name string*/
    fgets(name, max, stdin);
    /* 'read' returns number of variables read */
    read = sscanf(name, "%s %s %s", first, mid, last);
    /* If we only read first name and last name */
    if (read == 2) printf("%s, %s", mid, first[0]);
    /* 'read' should be 3 if we read all three variables */ 
    if (read == 3) printf("%s, %s %s", last, first[0], mid[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it gives me segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Conventionally, macros are all uppercase and underscores. For example, `SIZE` and `MAX`. Also, you should consider defining `max` as `(size * 4)` instead of just `size * 4` to avoid unexpected results when it gets replaced in a more complex expression.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks! This is noted.

Comment: @John3136 I'm trying to print only the first letter of the first name.

Comment: @JohnDoe Then why are you using `%s`? (should be `%c`)

Comment: Note you can always get the first character by dereferencing the pointer, e.g. `if (read == 3) printf ("%s, %c %c\n", last, *first, *mid);` Also, you don't need `stdlib.h`, you are not using anything it provides.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the advice! Also, what can I do in the future to word my question better? It seems that I'm getting downvoted.

Comment: Honestly, it's a phase of the moon thing on downvotes. If I had to guess, the downvotes were due to the basic nature of the *format string* question that could be answered by referencing the **man page**. I don't think the number of downvotes were warranted. Sometimes if you get one, there are bands of juvenile downvoters that pile on as well. I don't know if that is the case here, but don't sweat it. They are 2pts. each -- it will come out in the wash. The takeaway is to check the easy references first, but we have all been stuck on forrest-and-the-trees issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second and last printout values are characters, not strings, so use `%c` instead of `%s`;

```
if (read == 2) printf("%s, %c", mid, first[0]);
if (read == 3) printf("%s, %c %c", last, first[0], mid[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks @DYZ this works! Not sure why am I getting downvotes on my question though. Is there something I can improve about the question?